# StompEndpoint NullPointerException Error on Unit Testing

Tags: java, spring-websocket

Here is my code block:

```
@Test
    public void testRegisterStompEndpoints() {
        // Arrange
        StompEndpointRegistry registry = mock(StompEndpointRegistry.class);
        WebSocketConfig webSocketConfig = new WebSocketConfig();

        // Act
        webSocketConfig.registerStompEndpoints(registry);

        // Assert
        verify(registry, times(1)).addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
    }
```

Whenever I try to test this method. I got an error like:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompWebSocketEndpointRegistration.withSockJS()" because the return value of "org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint(String[])" is null

`registerStompEndpoints` is yellow underlined.

Can anyone please help me to fix this?

Comment: Your mock needs to be set up to return something non-null when `addEndpoint` is called on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: And by thew way, always include the full stack trace in questions.